# need help creating a button group pulled to right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a toolbar with a group of buttons on the left and another group of buttons on the right.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="span1">
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addStudent = true"><i class="icon-plus"
                                   "icon-white"></i></button>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-chevron-right
      icon-blue"></i></button>
      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-blue"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /btn-toolbar -->
  </div>
</div>
```

However the code above places both the button groups in separate lines, and also doesnt pull the second group to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull-right is working, you're just not giving the buttons any space horizontally so they are vertically flowing instead.

For example, change your "span1" to "span10" to provide some space for the chevron buttons to be floated.